# How to use the result of a JSR223 Pre-Processor script once for thread?

Tags: multithreading, post, jmeter, jsr223

I have 100 threads for 100 iterations. I want to use the result of a script as body of a HTTP POST request, it will has to be different for each thread.
FOR EXAMPLE: 100 thread - 100 iterations, I want 100 different requests.

Answer (score 0):

[JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) has `sampler` shortcut, if JSR223 Pre-Processor is applied to the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler the `sampler` is mapped to [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

Therefore you can add the generated value to the body of the HTTP Request sampler as:

```
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', body, '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

if you declare `body` as:

```
def body = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20)
```

you will see that each threads sends a random string of 20 alphanumeric characters for each virtual user on each iteration.

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements.